# Browsers: what makes restart required?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, installation

I am making a site that requires OpenLight to work, and I noticed that after installing it, Firefox requires a restart to start interpreting the fact that OpenLight is installed. What makes the restart required?

I noticed that once Adobe Flash is installed it starts working right away. Does this have to do with the installer? Or is there any way via JavaScript of forcing Firefox to re-read everything like a restart? Not sure what would be the way around this.

Answer (score 0):

All firefox extensions require a restart. Plugins such as Flash can work around this, but you cannot 'force a refresh' of the environment, unfortunately.

Comment: But why? Why can Flash do it? :)

Comment: this is not true anymore. Most extensions still do, but some of the more minor ones don't.

Comment: As Tim mentioned, I might very well be wrong. Flash is not a regular firefox add-on, it's a plugin.. like quicktime. Works quite different and in a separate process. in any case, if Tim is right, you'll need to change the OpenLight add-on to allow this.

Comment: In the context of Firefox extensions and not plugins, Firefox calls restartless addons "[bootstrapped extensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Extensions/Bootstrapped_extensions)" and the key thing is they can't use XUL overlays.

Answer (score 0):

It can happen due to a couple things. First off is if the plugin has been loaded before. If so and if the plugin developers wrote some code to support it, the new plugin can be swapped in without a restart because the plugin already exists in the namespace.

Second, is if the plugin is not making calls that require access to the core of browser. If the plugin does not need to than it can be bootstrapped in without a restart. Access to the chrome is a big reason to need to restart, see this [bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=564667) in Firefox.